# Cambiar el lenguaje de salida de moment.js react native

Tags: react-native, momentjs, datetimepicker

Modificar la salida de texto de un datetimepicker en react native.!

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import DateTimePicker from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
import moment from 'moment';

moment.locale('es');

export default class DateTimePickerTester extends Component {

  constructor() {

    super()
    this.state = {
      isVisible: false,
      chosenDate: '',
      selectedDate: '07:00 AM'
    }
  }

  handlePicker = (datetime) => {
    this.setState({
      isVisible: false,
      chosenDate: moment(datetime).format('LLLL')
    })
  }

  hidePicker = () => {
    this.setState({
      isVisible: false
    })
  }

  showPicker = () => {
    this.setState({
      isVisible: true
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignContent: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{color:'red', fontSize:20}}>
          {this.state.chosenDate}
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showPicker}>
          <Text>Ver</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <DateTimePicker

        datetime={moment().toDate()}
        is24Hour={true}
          isVisible={this.state.isVisible}
          onConfirm={this.handlePicker}
          onCancel={this.hidePicker}
          mode={'datetime'}
          datePickerModeAndroid={'spinner'}

        />
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

obtengo como salida

**Wednesday, January 23, 2019 5:37 PM**

***quiero obtener la fecha en español.***

Comment: si estas usando la versión de moment con soporte para locales? https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes tambien importar el lenguaje:

```
import 'moment/locale/es';
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona perfectamente